# how to make a javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, object

in trying to learn javascript objects so I thought I would write a simple program and then convert it to object based code. im unsure where im going wrong. so heres the original code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  #canvas { background: #ddd; border:5px black ridge; }
  </style>
  <script>
  function start() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var angle = 163;
  var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  var speedX = 1.5, speedY = 0.05, x = 0, y = 100;
  draw();
  function draw() {
  x += speedX;
  angle += speedY;
  y += Math.sin(angle) * radians;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = y;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", start);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300"></canvas>
  <h2 id="test"></h2>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and heres what ive got so far with the object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas { background: #ddd; border:5px black ridge; }
</style>
<script>
function start() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var cW = ctx.canvas.width, cH = ctx.canvas.height;

var enemy = {
   _x: 1,
   _y: 10,

   create: function(x, y, xv, range) {
      var obj = Object.create(this);
      obj.setX(x);
      obj.setY(y);
      obj.speedX(xv);
      obj.ySin(range);
      return obj;
   },
   setX: function(value) {
      this._x = value;
   },
   setY: function(value) {
      this._y = value;
   },
   getX: function() {
      return this._x;
   },
   getY: function() {
      return this._y;
   },
   speedX: function(spd) {
   this._x += spd;
   },
   ySin: function(rangeOfAngle) {
   var radians = rangeOfAngle * Math.PI / 180;
   rangeOfAngle += 0.05;
   this._y += Math.sin(rangeOfAngle) * radians;
  return this._y;
   },
   addTo: function(v2) {
      this._x += v2.getX();
      this._y += v2.getY();
   },
   update: function() {
   this.speedX(1.5);
   this.ySin(this._y);
   }
 };



var p = enemy.create(0, 100, 1, 10);
render();

function render() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(p.getX(), p.getY(), 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
p.update();
ctx.fill();
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = p.getY();

requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
}
window.addEventListener("load", start);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300"></canvas>
<h2 id="test"></h2>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: You failed to explain what the problem is.

Comment: @pointy im trying to replicate the first code intop an object literal form but it isn't working. can someone explain where im going wrong in the second bit of code

Comment: @8bitgamer: But *what* is not working?

Comment: @Bergi. if you run both code blocks you will see the difference. I think the problem is I cant seem to pass a variable into the object. not sure.

Comment: just by comparing your code, you construct your enemies with different parameters. So why do you think there wouldn't be a difference?

Comment: hmm I thought they were the same. can you tell me where its different?